# Select a word and click it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a website containing products and descriptions. Products can also have tags and tags are basically just words ([a-zA-Z]+) that can be part of those descriptions. And what I want to do is to allow the user to click on any word in the description that is also a tag so he can see all products that have this tag. Sounds simple, right?
The challenge is that the descriptions are just plain text without markup. I could have the server add additional mark-up for all the tags in the description but that slows things up too much. Besides, it makes the site less attractive if I e.g. add hyperlinks to those tags. so it was suggested by someone in my team to keep it simpler and only add the mark-up when it is needed.
The idea is that the user can move his mouse above a word. If it happens to be a tag, it gets highlighted for as long as the mouse is above it. When the user clicks it, it would open the tag selection page and show the related products. It is also not too difficult to know which words are tags in the description since a simple regular expression can provide me a distinct list of words, which I then compare with the list of tags in the database. No problem there.
But my problem is the JQuery that can detect single words in the description and highlight them! As I said, I don't want to add additional mark-up in the description, not even client-side. So my JQuery will need to do this 'on the fly'. Any suggestions for this word detection function?

(It is no problem if it also works on words outside the description, although it is nicer if it only works on words in the description.)

Comment: Did I get that right? You'll think you'll speed things up by scanning / mapping each word of your page when the user moves his mouse? What about touch devices by the way? Do you think this is normal behavior - that a user goes over the text line by line, when there is no indication that it is clickable?

Comment: Won't be used by touch devices so no problem there. But the problem of including the mark-up to the description before sending it to the client is that it makes the page much bigger and I need to save bandwidth. There can be a lot of tags in these descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some like below:

```
$(".word_split").lettering('words');   
linkableTags = ['Lorem','fermentum','Nullam','volutpat']
$("span[class^='word']").click(function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    if ( $.inArray( selectedText , linkableTags ) != -1 ){
        $(this).html('<a href="#"><u>'+$(this).text()+'</u></a>');
    }
});
```

On the content

```
<p class="word_split">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit interdum fermentum. Aenean fermentum imperdiet augue, et venenatis lectus semper vel. Phasellus faucibus nulla in quam egestas eleifend. Cras tristique augue eget libero tristique condimentum. Mauris eget diam eget risus feugiat rutrum. Duis placerat lorem quis augue semper porttitor. Nullam iaculis dui feugiat erat condimentum rutrum. Sed at accumsan diam. Maecenas ut urna id velit posuere auctor in vel dui. Aenean consectetur dui in leo faucibus sed feugiat dui blandit. In accumsan diam vitae erat volutpat volutpat aliquam nunc euismod. Vivamus viverra lorem nulla. Quisque justo quam, adipiscing sit amet auctor non, laoreet sit amet nisl. Donec euismod lorem ac mi dictum volutpat. Donec ligula mi, varius ac auctor at, sollicitudin id elit. In auctor sodales ipsum nec consectetur. Sed lacinia varius nibh vitae vulputate.<p>
```

with the css applied on:

```
.word_split span:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find your use case a bit crazy, but this can be done with the [jquery highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html). Using this plugin, you would simply call the following jquery command to highlight a word, anywhere within the body of the page

```
$("body").highlight("word");
```

Please note this will highlight *all* examples of that word, not just what the mouse is currently over.

Answer (score 1):

I would also go for a plugin like highlight, like @roryok suggested. I have some sample code for you :)

**LINK:** http://jsfiddle.net/nc20a48e/

```
<script>
$("body #tags a").click(function(){
    $("body #bodyText").unhighlight();
    $("body #bodyText").highlight($(this).text());
    return false;
});     
</script>
```